# API que tenga objetos dentro del principal

Tags: php, api

Tengo esta API:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $json = '';
        $banner = true;
        $id=$_GET["id"];
        $connection = new MySqlServerConnection();


        $query = 'SELECT s.id,s.description,s.ipAddress,r.id AS readingId,r.value as readingValue,r.registerDate as readingDate FROM stations as s
                            INNER JOIN readings as r on s.id = idStation
                            WHERE  s.id = ?';
        $result=$connection->executeQuery($query,array($id));

            $json .= '{"status":0, "stations":[';
            foreach ($result as $row) {
            $row = (Object)$row;
            if(!$banner) { $json .= ','; } else { $banner = false; }
            $json .= '{
                "id": "'.$row->id.'",
                "description": "'.$row->description.'",
                "ipAddress": "'.$row->ipAddress.'",
                "readingId": "'.$row->readingId.'",
                "readingValue": "'.$row->readingValue.'",
                "readingDate": "'.$row->readingDate.'"
            }';
        }

        $json .= ']}';
        echo $json;

    }
```

Los `3` primeros datos pertenecen a `stations`, y los siguientes `3` a `readings` por medio de la tabla stations hago un `inner join` trayendo los datos de `reading` dependiendo que `stations` se seleccione.

Quisiera que quedara algo asi:

```
status: 0,
stations: {
    id: X,
    description: XXX,
    ipAddress: XXX.XXX.X.X,
    readings: 
    [
      {
      "readingId":   XXX,
      "readingValue" XXX:,
      "readingDate"  XXX: 
      }
    ]
}
```

He intentado varias manera pero no tengo exito, ¿Alguien que me pudiera ayudar con esto?

Gracias.

Comment: y por que creas el **JSON** a mano teniendo en PHP funciones como `json_encode`?

Comment: De esta manera yo los he aprendido, y me ha resultado, si pudiras ayudarme o guiarme en esto te agradeceria,

Comment: Haz caso a @shadow, hacerlo a mano es una perdida de tiempo. Haz un array multidimesional todo lo complejo que se te ocurra y simplemente haz `echo '<pre>; print_r(json_encode($array_complejo)); echo '</pre>` y veras la estructura. No tienes que trabajar con texto json, usa un array u objeto y cuando tengas todos los datos, simplemente haces un `echo json_encode($datos);` La ayuda oficial:  http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php